# Measuring Method Execution Time for a Java Web Service in a Production Environment

Tags: java, performance, benchmarking, production-environment

I'm interested in finding out the best way to measure the execution time of methods within a Java web service I'm working on.

The service will be deployed to multiple clients and hence run in multiple different production environments (clients tend to have varying setups as dictacted by their requirements), and its been decided the service should log the execution time for processing requests to provide some indication of possible performance issues.

So far, most of the suggestions (such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3382954/measure-execution-time-for-a-java-method) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302026/measuring-java-execution-time-memory-usage-and-cpu-load-for-a-code-segment)) I've seen are to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` at the beginning and end of the code I'm interested in and calculate elapsed time, but is that really the best solution to this problem for a production environment?

**How suitable is `System.currentTimeMillis()` for measuring method execution time, and are there any alternatives?**

**EDIT 0:** To clarify, a key requirement is that this execution measurement should be deployed as part of the standard deployment to collect data so that it can be referred to should a performance related support issue be raised, as the service forms part of a complex system of new and legacy components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Spring Framework 'StopWatch' class:

- http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.0.1/api/org/springframework/util/StopWatch.html

You can even use AOP, this way you can profile code without changing it

- http://www.unicon.net/node/740

Comment: +1 - Use AOP with Spring - this is the best combo. We simply annotate the methods that need 'monitoring' and then write a AOP point cut around these annotations and register an aspect to measure the time performance.

Comment: The AOP approach looks good, but unfortunately I've run into some errors trying to use it, as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437769/why-isnt-the-spring-aop-xml-schema-properly-loaded-when-tomcat-loads-reads-bea

Answer (score 1):

Logging the time elapsed is fine, but you need to time it on the client side to really understand how long it's taking.  That will additionally tell you how much time you're spending in data transfer which could indicate an I/O bottleneck.

Comment: Depends on what you want to measure

Comment: Good point, although we're not so interested in the transfer time, as it's beyond our control

Comment: Even if the network part is out of your control, the size of the request is part of the application design. In fact we just had a case of a ridiculously sized XML document being sent to a request when much of it wasn't needed.  Trimming it down to essentials made a significant increase in transactions/s.

Answer (score 1):

System.currentTimeMillis() is suitable if your application will take more than 1 or 2 milliseconds to execute (although its precisions might be greater than the ms depending on your OS).

You might prefer using System.nanoTime() which can be fare more precise, but not to the nanosecond. Please note its precision also depends on your underlying system.

Both these methods are quite low-level (need you to manage timestamps) but have a lower overhead than more high-level API.