# Why isn't the Spring AOP XML schema properly loaded when Tomcat loads & reads beans.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, xsd

I'm trying to use [Spring's Schema Based AOP Support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-schema) in Eclipse and am getting errors when trying to load the configuration in Tomcat.

There are no errors in Eclipse and auto-complete works correctly for the aop namespace, however when I try to load the project into eclipse I get this error:

> 09:17:59,515  WARN XmlBeanDefinitionReader:47 - Ignored XML validation warning 
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

Followed by:

> SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 39 in XML document from /WEB-INF/beans.xml is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:config'.
>
> Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'aop:config'.

Based on this, it seems the schema is not being read when Tomcat parses the beans.xml file, leading to the `<aop:config>` element not being recognised.

My beans.xml file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd 
        http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws 
        http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">

    <!--import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" /-->
    <!--import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" /-->
    <!--import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" /-->

    <!-- NOTE: endpointName attribute maps to wsdl:port@name & should 
                be the same as the portName attribute
                in the @WebService annotation on the IWebServiceImpl class -->
    <!-- NOTE: serviceName attribute maps to wsdl:service@name & should be 
                the same as the serviceName attribute in the @WebService 
                 annotation on the ASDIWebServiceImpl class -->
    <!-- NOTE: address attribute is the actual URL of the web service 
                (relative to web app location) -->
    <jaxws:endpoint
            xmlns:tns="http://iwebservices.ourdomain/"

            id="iwebservices"
            implementor="ourdomain.iwebservices.IWebServiceImpl"
            endpointName="tns:IWebServiceImplPort"
            serviceName="tns:IWebService"
            address="/I"
            wsdlLocation="wsdl/I.wsdl">
            <!-- To have CXF auto-generate WSDL on the fly, comment out the above wsdl 
            attribute -->

            <jaxws:features>
                    <bean class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature" />
            </jaxws:features>
    </jaxws:endpoint>


    <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="myAspect" ref="aBean">

    </aop:aspect>
    </aop:config>


</beans>
```

The `<aop:config>` element in my `beans.xml` file is copy-pasted from the [Spring website](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-schema) to try and remove any possible source of error

**Can anyone shed any light on why this error is occurring and what I can do to fix it?**

Comment: Try `http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd` instead of `http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd`, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Tried `http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd` instead of `http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd`: Made no difference, same errors occurred

Comment: Thanks for improving the formatting org.life.java, I was wondering what I should do to make the exceptions more readable

Comment: OK, well this all looks OK< which suggests that it's a classpath problem.

Comment: it seems ok after skaffman's thing

Comment: I run into this problem today, it seems that 's because I forgot to add aop jar into pom.xml and re-run "mvn eclipse:eclipse" (I'm using Maven).

Comment: I am also getting the same error
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
I am trying to create REST web service using cxf and camel. But this error doesn't let me do it.
I have added camel-spring.jar, spring framework jars, cxf 2.7.5 jars
Any solution?

Comment: Sometimes it is better to specify the version you are using 
i.e. http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/springsource-tool-suite/69802-spring-ide-problems-with-xml-validation?p=474179#post474179

Answer (score 3):

Check that you have the Spring AOP jar (spring-aop.jar) in the WEB-INF/lib folder of your webapp.

That jar contais the specified XSD.