# Tomcat unable to read the schema document

Tags: spring, tomcat, proxy, xml-parsing, dwr

We are trying to add DWR for current project and the code that does this is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
       http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
       http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <dwr:configuration />
    <dwr:annotation-config />
    <dwr:url-mapping />

    <dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true" >
        <dwr:config-param name="activeReverseAjaxEnabled" value="true"/>
    </dwr:controller>
```

But after adding the DWR related stuff Tomcat basically throws an exception when the `<dwr:configuration />` is added to the Spring XML file and throws the below error on the browser:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 24 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/webmvc-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 26; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'dwr:configuration'.
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:388)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:98)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:95)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:36)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:106)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:150)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

root cause

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 26; cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'dwr:configuration'.
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:449)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(XMLSchemaValidator.java:3228)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1908)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:757)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:240)
    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:93)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:458)
    org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:388)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:195)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:159)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
    org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
    org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:71)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:98)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:95)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:79)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:55)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:36)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:188)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:106)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:356)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:150)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
```

When analyzing the error and looking at the Tomcat logs it looks like Tomcat is unable to read the schema document but this only happens when it tries to do so on the DWR's schema [ie., http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd] and throws an exception as below:

```
[24 Feb 2012 17:02:17,272] WARN  [http-8040-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Ignored X
ML validation warning
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 24; columnNumber: 26; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'htt
p://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the docu
ment could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>.
```

I have tried to google and look at the answers at stack overflow. The popular answers are from the below sites, state that its a classpath issue.

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?35417-The-matching-wildcard-is-strict-but-no-declaration-can-be-foun-aop-scoped-proxy

[Why isn't the Spring AOP XML schema properly loaded when Tomcat loads & reads beans.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4437769/why-isnt-the-spring-aop-xml-schema-properly-loaded-when-tomcat-loads-reads-be)

What made me think that its not a classpath issue is that the same program works perfectly fine when I try to run from home. ie., Tomcat is able to access and parse the dwr schema and this appears to me as a firewall or a proxy issue. And its true that we access internet through company's proxy. But I am able to access all the DWR schemas from my browser perfectly.

Is this a proxy issue? If so, how do I add a proxy to Tomcat's configuration. More over I am confused why only the DWR schema is inaccessible, where as w3.org and spring.org schema's are perfectly working.
Please point if my understanding of the technical aspects are flawed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run in a DWR XML Scheme problem one year ago (version 3.0 M1). They make a mess of `spring-dwr-2.0.xsd` and `spring-dwr-3.0.xsd` and did not add the spring.schema location for 3.0 xsd in ther jar. -- May you have the same problem. But first make sure that you deploy the `dwr.jar` correct!

If the `dwr.jar` does not contain a file `META-INF\spring.schemas` that contains the line:

```
http\://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd=org/directwebremoting/spring/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd
```

then my solution will help you. *(If the `dwr.jar` contains that line, then the problem is an other one.)*

---

To solved the problem, I created a new jar (`dwr-xsd.jar`) file that contains the two xsd files and a `spring.schemas` file.

To build such an jar:

download the 2 dwr xsd jars (`spring-dwr-2.0.xsd` and `spring-dwr-3.0.xsd`) and put them in the package `org.directwebremoting.spring`

Then add this `spring.schemas` file to the `META-INF` directory:

```
 http\://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd=org/directwebremoting/spring/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd
 http\://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd=org/directwebremoting/spring/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd
```

(The file must and with an line break! - I can not make it visible in SO)

No add `dwr-xsd.jar` and `dwr.jar` to your application.

Answer (score 2):

Ralph: I tried your solution, and everything seemed OK as you said in the beginning ie., spring.schemas was mapped correctly. But soon I found that version number is a problem. Just describing the whole thing so it could be useful for others too.

I tried the same with (DWR schema works) and without internet (does not work) connection which led me to the below discussion in SO and which was also useful along with your answer.

[Spring schemaLocation fails when there is no internet connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729307/spring-schemalocation-fails-when-there-is-no-internet-connection)

I saw the mapping was incorrect firstly and I changed the beans definition in the XML for DWR as follows:

```
   http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
   http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd">
```

from the existing:

```
http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr
http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd">
```

So there are two problems

1. The spring-dwr is missing in http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd">
2. The version is changed to spring-dwr-2.0.xsd from spring-dwr-3.0.xsd

The reason for #1 seems to be the spring.schemas file in META-INF is mapped this way

```
http\://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd=org/directwebremoting/spring/spring-dwr-2.0.xsd
```

For point #2, basically the DWR jar file (named as dwr-3.0.M1.jar) though its version says as 3.0 contains only 2.0 version of xsd and has the appropriate mapping in spring.schemas. So when I changed it worked offline [though I am yet to check on the fire-walled office network. But I think it will not try to fetch from online when it can find the content offline].

Thanks so much for the answer

Comment: Only to clarify your "anwer": did my tip: "create your own `dwr-xsd.jar` work?

Comment: I did not create a new dwr-xsd.jar but instead updated the xsd in the old dwr.jar file itself with the mapping as above.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not a case with yours. But in such a scenario, do clean and make a fresh build. Reason being the older spring jar and xsd from there would be taken if the two jars exits. Hope that helps for other guys .... generically this exception will be thrown for many reasons.