# Intent and start activity from string

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a little problem. I want to start activity but in something other way. I know that

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTwo.class);
```

initialize intent and after that I can `startActivity`. But I want do something like that:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MyString.class);
```

I have no `nameActivity.class`, but I want change on string.class. How I can start activity when I have string name of class?

Comment: What exactly is the scenario? Are you trying to start an activity based on some STRING value which will be used as the name for the Activity to be launched?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754855/how-can-i-start-a-new-android-activity-using-a-string

Comment: You can use reflection but is it really necessary?

Comment: When you have for example ActivityFirst.class I want to have string instead ActivityFirst and this is necessary

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I start a new android activity using a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754855/how-can-i-start-a-new-android-activity-using-a-string)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:
`startActivity(this, Class.forName(yourStringClass));`

Comment: The constructor Intent(TabsGenerator, Class<capture#2-of ?>) is undefined too :)

Comment: try the casting: `(Class<? extends Activity>)Class.forName("YourClass")`

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(TabsGenerator.this, (Class<? extends Activity>)Class.forName(StringClassname)); doesn't work too. The same error

Comment: Are you writting the full class name? With package. "com.youpackge.YourClass" Also you can try with: intent.setClassName(context,target);

Comment: try with new Intent().setClassName

Answer (score 3):

You can look up a `Class` by name using `Class.forName("MyString")`

Answer (score 2):

Just use....

```
  Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(activity,"packageName"+"className");
  startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Class<?> c =Class.forName("YOUR STRING" );
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, c);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The constructor Intent(TabsGenerator, Class<capture#2-of ?>) is undefined

Comment: Forgot to mention- the class name should be the fully qualified class name. Suppose the package name is com.something and the String is "THESTRING" then the fully qualified name will be - com.something.THESTRING .. Hope this helps

Comment: @Anukool : Please Edit your answer and put this comment in it.