# StartActivity from string

Tags: android, string, android-activity, xamarin

I want to start Activity using Aktywnosc string from Kalkulator in Xamarin Android Visual Studio

```
public class Kalkulator
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Nazwa { get; set; }
        public string Aktywnosc { get; set; }
        public string Krotki_opis { get; set; }
        public string Zrodlo { get; set; }
        public string Ineksowanie { get; set; }
    }
```

The Activity is in Resource.biblioteka folder.
I'm trying:
[Intent and start activity from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850212/intent-and-start-activity-from-string)

and this

[How can I start a new android activity using a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754855/how-can-i-start-a-new-android-activity-using-a-string)

```
var e_nacisniety = Kalkulator.Lista_kalkulatorow().First(p=>p.Id == e.Position);
            var act = "Resources.biblioteka." + e_nacisniety.Aktywnosc;
            StartActivity(new Intent().SetClassName(this, act));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is the Activity that you are trying to start:

```
namespace SushiHangover
{
    [Activity(Name = "Resources.biblioteka.SomeActivity", Label = "SomeActivity")]
    public class SomeActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Using the .Net Namespace/Class Name:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, Type.GetType("SushiHangover.SomeActivity"));
StartActivity(intent);
```

#### Using the Java Package/Class Name:

```
var intent = new Intent(this, Java.Lang.Class.ForName("Resources.biblioteka.SomeActivity"));
StartActivity(intent);
```