# Unable to start New Activity from old fragment?? Button click is doing nothing

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.android

```
On Fragment : 


 public override void OnViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {           
                buttonRedirect = View.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.send);
                buttonRedirect.Click += BtnOption_Click;
            }

    private void BtnOption_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {                        
                string imageString = "Some Data I am sending"
                StartNewActivity();
            }
    private void StartNewActivity()
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(this.Activity, 
                typeof(New Activity Page));
                intent.PutExtra("ImageString", imageString);
                StartActivity(intent);
            }
```

I am a beginner in Xamarin android but unable to decode this.Debugger is going to StartNewActivity() when pressing button , but doing nothing ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272879/4984832