# How to redirect to another activity with the short class name

Tags: android

Suppose I have two Activity(under the same package):

HomeActivity(The launcher activity)

SpinnerActivity

Both of them are registered at the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Now I try to create a method to implement the activity jump:

```
private void redirectToActivity(String dest) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClassName(this,dest);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

And I call it in the `HomeActivity`:

```
redirectToActivity("SpinnerActivity");
```

But I got this error:

> Unable to find explicit activity class {com.app/SpinnerActivity};
>   have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

I tried to add this line:

```
intent.setPackage("com.app");
```

It does not work.

What's the problem?

Comment: Instead of using String maybe you could use Class variable ?

Comment: Can you post your manifest file ? 
If your activity name in the manifest is ".SpinnerActivity", try to start it with : 
redirectToActivity(".SpinnerActivity");

Comment: See if changing `intent.setClassName(this,dest);` to `intent.setClassName(getApplicationContext(), dest);` works.

Comment: @Yume117:I have to use the string because I get the activity name by user selecting through a ListView.

Comment: @nbe_42: Yes, in the manifest it is ".SpinnerActivity", I have changed to `redirectToActivity(".SpinnerActivity")`, I still got the same error.

Comment: @vikram: I have tried and I got the same error.

Comment: Here is what i meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754855/how-can-i-start-a-new-android-activity-using-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Define it globally or in OnCreate() method

// If your all Activity is with in the same package then this approach is going to work.

```
final String packageName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
final Context context = this;

// call your method like this i.e SpinnerActivity
         private void redirectToActivity(String dest) {

                  try {
                        Class c = Class.forName(packageName + "." + dest);
                        startActivity(new Intent(context, c));
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, String.valueOf(e), 5000).show();
                    }
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.app/SpinnerActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

your package-name is odd. i am used to something like "com.company.appname" and you got com.app/SpinnerActivity. Have you tried thinking in that direction?

Comment: Since this is a application for learning android. So I use the `com.app` as the package name, does this matter?