# Why get "Unable to find explicit activity class" error?

Tags: android, kotlin, appicon, android-splashscreen, android-activity-alias

I changed application icon if user is gold user. When if the user is not gold after I changed that, don't load splash activity again. I tried create two alias actvity for these two sitatuan but I can't change icon with two alias. I tried deleted `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>` in SplashActivity but didn't solve. When I use these code without call from HomeFragment. Why have this issue now?

HomeFragmet.kt

```
if (clientPreferences.getIconType() != moneyCardType){
                                clientPreferences.setIsMoneyGold(moneyCardType)
                                clientPreferences.setIconType(moneyCardType)
                                val i = Intent(requireContext(), SplashActivity::class.java)
                                startActivity(i)
                            }
```

SplashActivity.kt

```
 if (clientPreferences.getIconType()){
            // disable old icon
            val manager = packageManager
            manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                ComponentName(
                    this@SplashActivity,
                    "com.grosmagazam.ui.SplashActivity"
                ),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            )

            // enable new icon
            manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                ComponentName(
                    this@SplashActivity,
                    "com.grosmagazam.ui.SplashActivityAlias"
                ),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            )
        } else {
            // enable old icon
            val manager = packageManager
            manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                ComponentName(
                    this@SplashActivity,
                    "com.grosmagazam.ui.SplashActivity"
                ),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            )
            // disable new icon
            manager.setComponentEnabledSetting(
                ComponentName(
                    this@SplashActivity,
                    "com.grosmagazam.ui.SplashActivityAlias"
                ),
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP
            )
        }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:screenOrientation="locked"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gros">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity-alias
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivityAlias"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_gros_money_gold_app"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_gros_money_gold_app"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="locked"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Gros"
        android:targetActivity=".ui.SplashActivity">

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity-alias>
```

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
> activity class
> {com.grosmagazam/com.grosmagazam.ui.SplashActivity}; have you
> declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml, or does your
> intent not match its declared ?
> at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2171)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1805)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5583)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2171)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1805)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5583)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:728)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5541)
> at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.java:709)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:6039)
> at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api16Impl.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:978)
> at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startActivity(ContextCompat.java:318)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentHostCallback.java:167)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1445)
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1433)
> at com.grosmagazam.ui.home.HomeFragment$initObservers$1.invoke(HomeFragment.kt:119)
> at com.grosmagazam.ui.home.HomeFragment$initObservers$1.invoke(HomeFragment.kt:70)
> at com.grosmagazam.ui.home.HomeFragment.initObservers$lambda$2(HomeFragment.kt:70)
> at com.grosmagazam.ui.home.HomeFragment.$r8$lambda$hkW920MYp10V-EdGJmRsINNTQI4(Unknown Source:0)
> at com.grosmagazam.ui.home.HomeFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda1.onChanged(Unknown Source:2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Intent(requireContext(), SplashActivity::class.java)`

When this activity is disabled, it's like it is absent in the Manifest. You need to start an alias instead.

It is not possible by class literal but you can specify its name as a string [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10904471/3050249).

Comment: Thank you so much.:) I added intent for SplashActivityAlias according your answer.