# Get application uptime

Tags: java, jvm

I've written an application in java and I want to add a feature to report the uptime of the application. Is there a Class/method in the JVM that can do this?

Should I save the timestamp when application starts, then calculate the difference with the current uptime in the moment of the request?

What's a better way to retrieve application uptime in Java?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [RuntimeMXBean.getUptime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getUptime--)

```
RuntimeMXBean rb = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
long uptime = rb.getUptime();
```

Comment: It is retuens JVM uptime not an application.

Comment: That's not necessarily different. In the Java EE context, they might be different things, but for standalone applications, runtime uptime and application uptime are one in the same.

Comment: and the jvm is the place where your application runs.

Comment: What's the difference? As far as application servers/servlet containers aren't taken into account? Based on the question we can assume the OP wants to how much time did it elapsed since the application startup, not the uptime percentage.

Answer (score 1):

The result is in milliseconds:

```
RuntimeMXBean mxBean = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean();
System.out.println(mxBean.getUptime());
```

See: [ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html#getRuntimeMXBean%28%29) javadoc.

Answer (score -1):

It is just like Heartbeat application. IN which You have write small application which communicate to your java application. Whenever You application start you have to store the time with date in file/database. Monitor application will check the application running or not. The monitor application also take difference of end time and start time sand display the application time.

Answer (score -6):

The solution I know is to use `System.currentTimeMillis()` as it's described [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/get-execution-time.shtml) and [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0132.html). There also was [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302026/measuring-java-execution-time-memory-usage-and-cpu-load-for-a-code-segment)

Comment: That's not what he's looking for. He is looking for application uptime (how long has the application been running).
Your solution will give the current time.

Comment: If you check links provided, you'll find that `currentTimeMillis` can be used to measure application uptime, i.e. by subtracting start time from current time in millis. So if we are speaking about my solution, it will not give current time