# Android how to get "application uptime"?

Tags: android

how can I get my application uptime?

I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6431668/3973591

But i have this error:

```
D/Error: ERR: file=BaseDexClassLoader.java
D/Error: ERR: class=dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader
D/Error: ERR: method=findClass line=56
D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
```

Can you help me?

Or do you have another solution?

Comment: Did you read the comment there?  That's JVM uptime, not an application.

Comment: And where do you want to know this information? Within the application itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how i can get my application uptime ?

"Uptime" does not really have a lot of meaning in Android. But, you are welcome to:

- Create a subclass of `Application`
- Override `onCreate()` and make note of the current time (e.g., `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`)
- Register that custom `Application` subclass in the manifest, via `android:name` on the `<application>` element

Then, your process' uptime is the current time minus the value saved in `onCreate()`.

> i found this :https://stackoverflow.com/a/6431668/3973591

That code principally is for Java servers, and that class does not exist on Android.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.  Already i have Application.
Also i think about this. But only we have this solution ? Android does not give you uptime ?

Comment: @Hasan: "Android does not give you uptime ?" -- not that I can think of. Again, it is not a useful metric on Android IMHO. Processes are supposed to come and go as needed.

Comment: There can be a need to track and test uptime, for digital signage or kiosk applications where a single Application is long running

Answer (score 0):

As of API 24, the following were added to Android:

- [Process.getElapsedCpuTime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process#getElapsedCpuTime())
- [Process.getStartElapsedRealtime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process#getStartElapsedRealtime())
- [Process.getStartRequestedElapsedRealtime()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process#getStartRequestedElapsedRealtime())
- [Process.getStartUptimeMillis()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process#getStartUptimeMillis())

Either of the following should work to provide an application uptime:

```
val appUptimeMs =  SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - Process.getStartElapsedRealtime()
```

```
val appUptimeMs = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - Process.getStartUptimeMillis()
```

If running on a pre-24 device, you will need a store a start time at application startup, as mentioned by CommonsWare.