# Asterisk/Java: How do I get the start time of a call after rebooting my Java app?

Tags: java, asterisk, pbx

I'm using Asterisk's AMI so that my Java app can receive events from the pbx. I'm currently relying on the NewChannelEvent to get the start time of the call.

However, when I reboot my system, I have no way to retrieve the start time of the call.

What is the most elegant way to solve this problem? Best case is I would like my Java app to receive an event with the call details.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get application uptime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431607/get-application-uptime)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the logs in the asterisk's Master.csv. it's in

```
/var/log/asterisk/cdr-csv/Master.csv
```

It will give you more useful data.

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk have two 3 mechanism for that

1) AMI

2) CEL https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=5242932
CEL allow you see multiple events, including start of call in database.

3) CDR https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+12+CDR+Specification
You will start of call too, but only after end of call.

Also you can change dialplan so it do func_odbc and mark start of call in your favorite table in dialplan.

```
---func_cdr.conf---
[put_active]
writesql=insert into active_calls(uniqueid,calldate,start,src,did,accountcode) values('${VAL1}','${VAL2}',1,'${VAL3}','${VAL4}','${VAL5}');
dsn=mysql_general
```

In extensions.conf

```
exten => _X.,1,Set(ODBC_put_active()=${CDR(uniqueid)},${CDR(start)},${CDR(src)},${CDR(did)},${CDR(accountcode)})
```